# from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage [CRITICAL] [App ] Unable to get a Window, abort

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, kivy

I'm a novice when it comes to computers so please go easy....

- Running Python 3.7 (32 bit) on Windows 10
- Using PyCharm
- Using Kivy 1.10.1

Running the below code:

```
from kivy.app import App
App().run()
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\callu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe "C:/Users/callu/OneDrive/Documents/Voting app/main.py"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\callu\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-06-01_54.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\callu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\callu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 26, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

I've read around 10 different questions with no luck to solving my problem. I've tried adding sdl2 and glew to PATH through the following route

```
C:\Users\callu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy_deps\sdl2
```

I've installed all the kivy dependencies. The odd thing is whenever I try to install the dependencies again it says requirement filled, already installed....but for sdl2 I can keep installing it and it never says this, it just installs the file as though it's the first time.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding `kivy.require('1.10.1')` and `import kivy`

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1')
from kivy.app import App
App().run()
```

Comment: Still getting the same error with that unfortunately

Comment: I've edited the answer with a stack question similar to yours that has already been answered.

Comment: @yemi.JUMP If you consider that the question has been answered in another post then you should mark it as a duplicate if you have the reputation to do so, or just leave a comment as you have done

Comment: Okay. Do I delete this answer? @eyllanesc

Comment: @yemi.JUMP It depends on you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll have a look later at the link and try the solutions (although I've probably already tried the proposed solutions)